# Toggling the format in the timeline causes the "S" (for "simultaneous dates") to move outside the table

Tags: bug, design, timeline

In the timeline for [Why is the Google Analytics cookie defined as "strictly necessary" and saved without consent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/374897/timeline), the "S" for "simultaneous dates" fits in the table for the default time format:

[image]

However, toggling the format to the longer form causes the "S" to move outside the table:

[image]

Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)? Or is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

---

**EDIT**

This also happens without toggling the format, when the year is also included:

[image]

(From [Is Stack Exchange accessible for the blind and visually impaired [...]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/358372/timeline))

Comment: At least it doesn't break the design catastrophically so that is a win ...

Comment: It's a bug, it's shown outside the `td` element it belongs to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE1TU.png